# Common Tool for CMake ToolChain

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform, toolchain

I started learning CMake from yesterday only. I'm a front end developer recently switched to a cross-platform project. So apologias for my silly questions.
I recently heard about `Toolchain`. So why we can't have a common toolchain tool to build projects for various platforms? (A tool with all kind of toolchains files we can simply use that tool to build our project for all platforms.) If there is anything available similar to that kindly share that link. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I am confused on what level you want this to happen. I mean do you on linux want to run command and have it generate visual studio compiled binaries and gcc and clang and Intel compiler? Do you want it to produce binaries for 1/2 dozen different operating systems ...

Comment: means my host machine is Mac and I want to generate build for linux,android ,ios,windows @drescherjm

Comment: I thought that is what cmake does....

Comment: The android ndk does this, to some extent. It takes a single cmakelists file and builds it for all four common Android architectures. If you have a library of toolchain files all you need is a loop to build all of them separately.